# Command Button inside composition page in JSF

Tags: jsf, primefaces, uiinclude

I have the same problem as user1598186 has stated in his question here : [p:commandButton doesn't call bean's method in an <ui:include> page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11954576/pcommandbutton-doesnt-call-beans-method-in-an-uiinclude-page)

However, no solution has been given (he has removed `<ui:include>` tags altogether and used variables instead)

Are there any ways of using `<ui:include>` and still have my backing bean's method executed, when I'm calling it inside the commandButton.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EL 2.2 method parameters (so, `#{bean.method()}` instead of `#{bean.method}`) can be used to pass a method signature that can be used in the `actionListener` attribute of a commandButton.  The following is an example of passing a ManagedBean property as well as passing a method signature:

**Main Page**

```
<ui:include src="/jointeam.xhtml">
  <ui:param name="propertyValue" value="#{managedBean.property1} />
  <ui:param name="method" value="#{managedBean.performAction()}" />
</ui:include>
```

**jointeam.xhtml**

```
...

<h:inputText value="#{propertyValue}" />

...

<p:commandButton value="Submit" actionListener="#{method}" />
```

You can see how powerful this is in terms of code reuse and for many instances is less verbose and easier to use than composite components.

Comment: Will the `<ui:param>` work even if the redirection is being done by a method in the bean?

eg: 

`<ui:include src="#{managedBean.navigation}">
      <ui:param name="method" value="#{managedBean.method}">
 </ui:include>`

Please help..

Comment: @sciFi I believe the src attribute takes a string property, so as long as navigation returns a valid FILE PATH then it should work.  Remember that this component includes an xhtml file, not requesting an xhtml page

Comment: i do return the name of a page (using if condition) in my bean, so it is a String that is returned as `my_page.xhtml`

But the parameter passed using `<ui:param>` is not being read inside my_page (which is inside `<ui:compostion>`. Am I doing something wrong? Please help..

Comment: @sciFi Hmmm... perhaps you can post your code in a seperate question?  It is hard to diagnose issues in the comments section.

Comment: I have posted it as a separate question [link is here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15002272/dynamic-ui-include-and-commandbutton). if my question is still not clear, please do tell me.. Any help will be really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: This won't work at all. The method expression is interpreted as a value expression. See the answer on OP's follow-up question.

Comment: @BalusC I understand that your answer works well too, but I am telling you, for right or wrong, the Primefaces actionListener attribute on commandButton being passed a method from ui:param in this way works. I am looking at my working code right now on Primefaces 3.2 and this code works for me, just on Primefaces CommandButton actionListener but it works.  Try it for yourself and see.

Comment: It'll probably be the EL 2.2 `()` on the method name. Does it work for you without them? And on different servers?

Comment: @BalusC I just tested and it does not work without the EL 2.2 () feature.

Comment: @BalusC Thank you for clarifying this, I learned something new today! :)